# StringTokenizer delimiters for each Character

Tags: java, delimiter, stringtokenizer

I've got a string that I'm supposed to use StringTokenizer on for a course. I've got my plan on how to implement the project, but I cannot find any reference as to how I will make the delimiter each character.

Basically, a String such as "Hippo Campus is a party place" I need to divide into tokens for each character and then compare them to a set of values and swap out a particular one with another. I know how to do everything else, but what the delimiter would be for separating each character?

Comment: @MouseEvent - no problem with the code, other than the delimiter itself. I just need to make each character a token. I've tried to put "", but it ignores the space then and prints the string out fully. Also tried regex, but it keeps telling me it's an illegal escape character.

Comment: well, your header gave the illusion of some bigger problem... see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use StringTokenizer  you could use like below

```
     String myStr = "Hippo Campus is a party place".replaceAll("", " ");
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(myStr," ");
```

Or even you can use split for this. And your result will be String array with each character.

```
String myStr = "Hippo Campus is a party place";
String [] chars = myStr.split("");

for(String str:chars ){
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: That works for me. I completely messed up in another area though. The tokens are Strings and can't be modified. So, now I have another thing to find.

Comment: You can use StringBuilder to create mutable Strings.

Comment: Actually, just checked the assignment again. Just says to use it in the process. So, it has worked separating all the tokens, which I can then throw into an array and work properly with. At this point 10 marks is not worth 2 evenings of work.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the String to an array. There is no delimiter for separating every single character, and it wouldnt make sense to use string tokenizer to do that even if there was.

You can do something like:

```
 char[] individualChars = someString.toCharArray;
```

Then iterate through that array like so:

```
for (char c : individualChars){
    //do something with the chars.
}
```

Comment: StringTokenizer is the requirement. Can't not use it.

Comment: @user1588867 if you really want You can use StringTokenizer with replaceAll to your string. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like make the string in to a Char array.

```
char[] simpleArray = sampleString.toCharArray();
```

This will split the String to a set of characters. So you can do the operations which you have stated above.